# How to use xll package at other computer

Tags: excel-dna, xll

I'm a learner about ExcelDNA.According to the example, I make it simple to test the package "FirstAddIn-packed.xll". When I finished it, I import it to excel and no problem and my computer has installed vs2019. Please look at the Images. But when I copy the package "FirstAddIn-packed.xll" to another computer it not work.
hope you reply. thank you very much.
My computer:
[image: My computer installed vs2019]
[image: My computer installed vs2019]
[image: My computer installed vs2019]

other computer:
[image: oter computer only have office and]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it works on your machine. In the background I see that your library is built to target .netstandard 2.0. This is not yet supported by Excel-DNA. You should make a new class library that targets .NET Framework, and then install the ExcelDna.AddIn package. You must also be using the packages.config style NuGet integration, and not the newer PackageReference style.

If you do all of that, it should work both on your machine and others.

Comment: Thank you very much, It's my mistake. You are right.

Comment: @Govert To confirm, if I can get it to work on my computer, saving the file then distributing it will ensure it works everywhere? Essentially, I'm trying to add functionality using C# without having to use regasm.

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus The best place to ask if you have an Excel-DNA question is on the Google group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/exceldna